Unable to recognise previous job names in gitlab pipeline
Build.yml
stages:
  - build

.build_template:
  stage: build
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/nextgen-app:$APP_TAG
  before_script:
    - |
      {
        echo "@paloma:registry=${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/81777/packages/npm/"
        echo "${CI_API_V4_URL#https?}/projects/81777/packages/npm/:_authToken=\${CI_JOB_TOKEN}"
      } | tee -a .npmrc
    - pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store
    - pnpm i
  script:
    - echo "Building ${PACKAGE_NAME}"
    - pnpm --filter="${PACKAGE_NAME}" run build
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_ID"
    paths:
      - apps/${PACKAGE_NAME}/.next/*
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - pnpm-lock.yaml
    paths:
      - .pnpm-store
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
    - changes:
        - "apps/${PACKAGE_NAME}/**/*"
        - "packages/ui-packages/${PACKAGE_NAME}/**/*"
  coverage: '/All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/'

build_article_micro_frontend:
  extends: .build_template
  variables:
    PACKAGE_NAME: article-micro-frontend

build_category_micro_frontend:
  extends: .build_template
  variables:
    PACKAGE_NAME: category-micro-frontend

publish.yml
stages:
  - publish

.publish: &publish
  stage: publish
  image: $ARTIFACTORY/docker
  variables:
    HARBOR_PROJECT: "eait"
    IMAGE_REPOSITORY: "harbor.darkside.ea.com/$HARBOR_PROJECT"
  services:
    - name: $ARTIFACTORY/docker:dind
  before_script:
    - |
      {
        echo "@paloma:registry=${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/81777/packages/npm/"
        echo "${CI_API_V4_URL#https?}/projects/81777/packages/npm/:_authToken=\${CI_JOB_TOKEN}"
      } | tee -a .npmrc
    - if [[ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH ]] ; then export TAG='latest' ; else export TAG=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME ; fi
    - if [[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG ]] ; then export TAG=$CI_COMMIT_TAG ; fi
    - mkdir -p ~/.docker
    - echo '{"auths":{"'$IMAGE_REPOSITORY'":{"username":"'$HARBOR_USER'","password":"'$HARBOR_PASSWORD'"}}}' >>  ~/.docker/config.json
  tags:
    - ceit-dind

# Image for article-micro-frontend
publish:article-micro-frontend:
  <<: *publish
  needs:
    - build_article_micro_frontend
  script:
    - export IMAGE_NAME=article-micro-frontend
    - export REPO="$IMAGE_REPOSITORY/$IMAGE_NAME"
    - docker build --file apps/article-micro-frontend/Dockerfile -t $REPO:$CI_PIPELINE_ID .
    - docker push $REPO:$CI_PIPELINE_ID

# Image for category-micro-frontend
publish:category-micro-frontend:
  <<: *publish
  needs:
    - build_category_micro_frontend
  script:
    - export IMAGE_NAME=category-micro-frontend
    - export REPO="$IMAGE_REPOSITORY/$IMAGE_NAME"
    - docker build --file apps/category-micro-frontend/Dockerfile -t $REPO@$CI_PIPELINE_ID .
    - docker push $REPO@$CI_PIPELINE_ID

I am using the needs keyword to depend on previous job but getting this error:
'publish:article-micro-frontend' job needs 'build_article_micro_frontend' job, but 'build_article_micro_frontend' is not in any previous stage

'publish:category-micro-frontend' job needs 'build_category_micro_frontend' job, but 'build_category_micro_frontend' is not in any previous stage

What did I miss? Please help

On which branch and under what conditions are you running the pipeline? build_article_micro_frontend does have a rules section, inherited from build_template. This might prevent the job from running
